# Slashes seperate arguments

Tags: nginx

Hello I have the following config in nginx:

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/ /$1.php;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/ /$1.php?$2=$3;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/ /$1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5;
}
```

It doesn't work as expected. Basically what I want to do is if someone requests www.example.com/request/test/value then request.php?test=value would be called ONLY if request.php exists, I want this to be done systematically for hundreds of files not just request.php which I use in this example. Also one should be able to visit /request and reach request.php (which I have already achieved)

Comment: The best solution is to [redesign the web application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Comment: not an option...

Comment: I've heard that many times...it almost always is the case that it _is_ an option.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Michael's comment, you can try something like this:

```
location ~ ^(?<phpfile>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $phpfile.php;
}

location ~ ^(?<phpfile>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<arg1>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<val1>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $phpfile.php?$arg1=$val1;
}
```

Here we use regex capture to capture different parts of the URI to variables, which are then used for the `try_files` directive.

I have not tested this approach, so I'm not sure if it works. If `try_files` doesn't seem to work, you can try this inside the location instead:

```
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        if (-e $phpfile.php) {
            rewrite ^ $phpfile.php;
        }
    }
```